# Does angular include the commented code/components also while building?

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

I have a few components that I do not currently, but may require it later. I know that the number of components increase the size of the build which makes the page to load slower. Does angular include the components whose imports are commented in `app.module.ts`. Incase if it includes these commented imports also then I have to delete them for the page to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sr about my post earlier.

Angular tree shaking components by looking at their selector in templates, class names in routers, or entry components. if they didn't appear in any of these. it will not be ignored.

To make sure of this, you can build project in production mode. and search for selectors of these components in file main.js to see whether it was built.

Answer (score 0):

Commented doesn't execute so your imports would not work and the components would not be present in the build which will reduce the bundle size.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! Is there any documentation that I can refer to?